# Comparison with string literal C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm writing a function for a program that allows a student to copy a template text file. This function checks the user's input to see if his desired template is allowed for his class.

I'm getting the error "Comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior" on lines 21 and 25. I have done "cout << name" to verify that variable is storing correctly, which it is, so I know that's not the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//TEMPLATE CHECK
//First you check to see if the student is allowed to use the template
int templateCheck()
{
    //Declare file name variable
    char name[256];

    //Prompt for user input
    cout << "Enter file name: ";

    //Cin user input
    cin >> name;

    //Begin check
    //CS221 is the first template you can't use
    if(name == "/home/cs221Temp.txt")
        cout << "You are not allowed to use CS221 templates./n";

        //CS 321 is the other template you can't use
        else if (name == "/home/cs321Temp.txt")
        cout << "You are not allowed to use CS321 templates./n";

        //Any others are okay (I commented these out since I'm just working on this function by itself)
        //else 
        //copyTemplate();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `strcmp` instead of `==`.

Comment: or, even much much better, use C++'s string class that *has* an overloaded == operator.

Comment: Use `std::string` - Even easier than using `strcmp`

Comment: You included `<string>`, but never used what's in it, namely `std::string`.  If you did that instead of `char name[40]`, you wouldn't have an issue.

Comment: Aside: you have another bug: you declare `name` as an array of length `256`, but you store arbitrary user input... which can be more than `255` characters long. (This would also be fixed with `std::string`)

Answer (score 4):

This statement

```
if(name == "/home/cs221Temp.txt")
```

compares for pointers being equal (which is unlikely), not their contents.
What you actually want is

```
if(strncmp(name,"/home/cs221Temp.txt",256) == 0)
```

or

```
std::string name;
```

in your function.

Comment: Actually, if he wants C-style strings, he should do `if( strncmp(name, "/home/cs221Temp.txt", 255) == 0 )`. One should learn to use `strncmp`/`strlcmp` from the beginning, for security reasons. 

Notice the 255 instead of 256, avoiding to compare over the null-byte end of string character.

Comment: @tnull Well, I agree in general that using `strncmp()` is more safe vs. using  `strcmp()`. Though name would have a serious problem not providing a `'\0'` terminated string, and detect a design problem.

Comment: Might be a 'design problem', but happens all the time. So, I impose the rule of thumb (at least on myself) to NEVER use `strcmp`/`strcpy` and so on. Just don't get in the habit of it. And when you have to think about what is the correct number argument to `strncmp`, you probably see your design flaws much earlier and more clearly.

Comment: @tnull It's a good rule, but not really relevant for the question/answer.

Comment: partly true. He should use `std::string`. However if he doesn't, I'd say always advise on using `strncmp`. So not actually relevant for the question, but your answer ;)

Comment: @tnull If you wish. But using 256 is OK  for a buffer allocated with `256` (`char name[256];`).

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare two C-style strings by `==`ing them. (C-style string literals just give you a pointer to the first character in a sequence of characters in RAM, ended by a 0 valued character, so you'd be comparing addresses instead of strings).

What you want to use would be the `strcmp` function from `stdlib`.

However, you're writing C++, not C.

So, I recommend using the `string` class, which *has* an overloaded `==` operator, so you *can* do

```
if (string1 == string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ (unlike in "similar" languages like JavaScript) when you use `==` on "strings" you are comparing pointers.
If you want to compare the strings' content, then you must use functions that are designed for that purpose. Like `strcmp()` from the standard C library